# Which should we use - jersey-grizzly or jersey-grizzly2

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

Which one is preferable to use jersey-grizzly or jersey-grizzly2? I am asking generally.

Comment: Do you have a special purpose in mind or just generally?

Answer (score 3):

From  [the announcment](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/jersey_grizzly_2_x_integration):

> "jersey-grizzly2" module has been finalized and provides same functionality as "jersey-grizzly"

The current stable release of [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/) is 2.3.11. Unless you have a particular reason to stick with the older 1.x series, you should pick Grizzly 2 and the corresponding `jersey-grizzly2`.